# How to run simple junit for restful webservices in java?

Tags: java, rest, testing, junit, mockito

I try to run unit tests for 2 methods. When I run `JUnit` test for `testRetrieveAllHotels_ServiceLayer()` method it works sucessfully, but when I try to run `JUnit` test for `testRetrieveAllHotels_WebLayer()` method, I get this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

This is the code:

```
package com.xxx.restfultesting.controller;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.header;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import com.xxx.restfultesting.business.HotelBusinessService;
import com.xxx.restfultesting.model.Hotel;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)             
@WebMvcTest(HotelController.class)  
public class HotelControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;    

    @MockBean
    private HotelBusinessService businessService;

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveAllHotels_ServiceLayer(){

        businessService.retrieveAllHotels();

        verify(businessService, times(1)).retrieveAllHotels();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveAllHotels_WebLayer(){

        HotelController hotelController = new HotelController();

        when(businessService.retrieveAllHotels()).thenReturn(               
                Arrays.asList(new Hotel(1, "Sofitel", 120, 20),
                        new Hotel(2, "Ibis", 50, 40),
                        new Item(3, "Marriot", 200, 15)));

        hotelController.retrieveAllHotels();

        verify(businessService, times(1)).retrieveAllHotels();
    }
```

HotelController:

```
package com.xxx.restfultesting.controller;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import com.xxx.restfultesting.business.HotelBusinessService;
import com.xxx.restfultesting.model.Hotel;

@RestController
public class HotelController {

    @Autowired
    private HotelBusinessService businessService;

    @GetMapping("/items")
    public List<Hotel> retrieveAllHotels() {

        System.out.println("Debugging 1"); 

        List<Hotel> hotels = businessService.retrieveAllHotels();

        return hotels; 
    }
```

HotelBusinessService:

```
package com.xxx.restfultesting.business;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.xxx.restfultesting.data.HotelRepository;
import com.xxx.restfultesting.model.Hotel;

@Component
public class HotelBusinessService {

    @Autowired
    private HotelRepository repository;

    public List<Hotel> retrieveAllHotels() {

        System.out.println("Debugging 2");

        List<Hotel> hotels = repository.findAll(); 

        return hotels;  
    }
}
```

I put System.out.println("Debugging 1") inside retrieveAllHotels() method from Controller and System.out.println("Debugging 2") inside retrieveAllHotels() method from Service. These are only for debugging. When I run JUnit test for 
testRetrieveAllHotels_ServiceLayer() method, it works successfully, but I don't get "Debugging 2" in the console.

When I run JUnit test for testRetrieveAllHotels_WebLayer() method I get the java.lang.NullPointerException error and I get "Debugging 1" in the console. I try to understand why there is not "Debugging 2" in the first case and how to run successfully the second method. Any feedback will be apreciated!

Comment: Please update the question: spring or spring-boot and what version do you use?

Comment: `HotelController.retrieveAllHotels` returns `items` which isn't declared. How does this code compile?

Comment: @Bart Sorry, it was a mistake, it return hotels.

Comment: @m4gic I use Spring Boot version 2.0.5

Comment: Are you sure `businessService` in `HotelController` is properly autowired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@WebMvcTest` - I think you are trying to write the controller test, where you have autowired `MockMvc` and mocked the service class.

In `testRetrieveAllHotels_ServiceLayer` test, you are trying to call a method that is in mocked service class and verify if that method is been called. The test will get succeeded since you have invoked the mock in the test itself.

In `testRetrieveAllHotels_WebLayer` test, you have created your own instance of the controller and using the mocked service. To fix this, you have to `Autowire` the controller in test or use constructor based injection in class and pass the mock to the constructor in the test

That will only fix the test but it is not the right way to test the controller. Things to fix:

- There is no need for `testRetrieveAllHotels_ServiceLayer` test. You can remove this test.
- `testRetrieveAllHotels_WebLayer` has to be updated like below:

  ```
  public void testRetrieveAllHotels_WebLayer(){

    when(businessService.retrieveAllHotels()).thenReturn(
          Arrays.asList(new Hotel(1, "Sofitel", 120, 20),
                  new Hotel(2, "Ibis", 50, 40),
                  new Item(3, "Marriot", 200, 15)));

    mockMvc.perform(
          get("/items"))
          .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(businessService, times(1)).retrieveAllHotels();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Thiru! I see that you have an interest for Kafka and I want to ask you something. I want to learn JMS and Kafka. Can you tell me a good place to learn JMS and Kafka? An Udemy course or something?

Comment: I started with PluralSight and then into the real project.